# Need help in choosing right caching strategy

Tags: caching, memcached

We car planning to store prices data to Memcache. prices are subject to car **variant** and **location(city)**. This is how it is stored in the database.

variant, city, price
21, 48, 40000

Now the confusion is that how do we store this data into Memcache.

**Possibility 1** : We store each price in separate cache object and do a multiget if the price of all variant belongs to a model need to be displayed on a single page.

**Possibility 2** : We store prices at the model, city level. Prices of all variants of a model will be stored in a single object. This object will be slightly heavy but multiget wouldn't be required.

Need your help in taking the right decision.

Comment: Hey! Did my answer help? If it answers your question, dont forget to accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: It all depends on how you want to expose the feature to your end users, and *what the query pattern looks like.*

For example:

1. If your flow is that a user can see all the variant prices on a detail page for a city, then you could use `<city_id>_<car_model_id>` as the key, and store all data for variants against that key (Possibility 2).
2. If the flow is that a user can see prices of all variants across cities on a single page, then you would need the key as `<car_model_id>` and store all data as Json against this key
3. If the flow is that a user can see prices of one variant at a time only for every city, then you would use the key `<city_id>_<car_variant_id>` and store prices.

One thing to definitely keep in mind is the frequency with which you may have to refresh the cache/ perform upserts, which in the case of cars should be infrequent (who changes the prices of a car every day/second). So, I would have gone with option 1 above (Possibility 2 as described by you).

Comment: In our case, both case 1 and case 3 are there. What should we do in that case?

Comment: @ssharma You will have to then maintain caches for both the use cases, with key format as discussed above. Though, in general, a car_model_id would rarely have more than 20 variants, so you could just do approach (1) above, and filter the data for use case (3) on the frontend which would help you in cost saving.